# To show that $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, can I write $F(x) = \int f(x) \; dx$?

Tags: calculus

If I want to show that $F(x)$ is antiderivative of $f(x),$ then usually I find $F'(x).$ And if $F'(x)=f(x)$, then $F$ is antiderivative, otherwise not.

My question is if I want to show that $F$ is antiderivative, can I also say that 
$$\int f(x)\, dx$$, and if $$\int f(x)\, dx = F(x),$$ then the answer is yes, otherwise not. Is not there a problem with a constant in this method. So for me it seems like that I cannot use it. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already have the solution. What we mean by $\int f(x)\ dx$ is really a family of functions that differ only by a constant. So what you do is you take this family of antiderivatives of $f$ and pick one. Say we call it $G$. So then if $G - F$ is a constant (technically *locally* a constant), then $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

But of course, the easiest method is to simply differentiatie $F$.

Comment: ...if the difference $G-F$ is *locally* constant, then...

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: I guess that's a good point.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2$ and $F(x)=1/3*x^3$. I want to show that F is antiderivative of f. So to do the other way I find that $\int f(x)\, dx = 1/3x^3+k$. So then what is my conclusion? Can I conclude that F is  one of the antiderivatives of f?

Comment: then what...?@emanuele

Comment: @Reader: You know that for every $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $x^3/3 + k$ is an antiderivative of $x^2$. You pick one $k$, say $k=2$ (this would work for any $k$). Take $G(x) = x^3/3+2$. $G(x) - F(x) = 2$, which is a constant, so you can conclude that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. But again, this is a roundabout way to do something pretty simple.

Comment: $\int f$ is the set of all antiderivatives. So you are right, if $F$ is one of the functions of $\int f$ it is, by definition, an antiderivative. My comment was to point out that the answer of @Javier had a little flaw (which he has corrected)